# "vue3 typescript" globalProperties variable is initialized to null When move a webpage

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

main.ts

```
const app = createApp(App)
        .use(router)
        .use(createPinia())
        .use(vuetify)
        .use(vue3GoogleLogin, googleLogin)

    const global = app.config.globalProperties;
    global.isDebug = true;
```

vue-shim

```
declare module '@vue/runtime-core' {
    interface ComponentCustomProperties {
        $isDebug: true;
    }
}
```

i expect this.$isDebug is true. but this.$isDebug is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there is an inconsistency between how you define the global property and how you access it.

Try this:

```
const globalProperties = app.config.globalProperties;
globalProperties.$isDebug = true;
```

Comment: I asked a question without checking it properly. thank you